# Action mode call back doesn't trigger

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, menu

I'm trying to implement a multiselection to share files in my recyclerview. For that I'm using an Action mode callback which is supposed to inflate a custom menu for my option. But after a long click nothing happen... Someone has an idea? It's very difficult to find good examples without seeing multiple complex methods.

```
        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {        // todo partager plusieurs fichier? + imprimer

        val actionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
            override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
                mode.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_file,menu)
                return true
            }

            override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
                isSelected = true

                return false
            }

            override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                return when (item.itemId) {
                    R.id.share -> {
                        // delete all the selected rows
                        mode.finish()
                        true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }
            }

            override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode) {
                isSelected = false
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You had just created your `ActionMode.Callback` object, but you are not doing anything with it. You can create it outside of your `ClickListener` and just use the `Activity` method `startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback)` inside of you `ClickListener`.

Read the documentation for more information:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

Comment: Thank! Of course stupid... I managed to make it work in my activity but for my adapter it's another story. This line stuck me:                 actionMode = startActionMode(actionModeCallback)      , how can I create a reference to my parent acitivity? In the docs they use this line :             actionMode = activity?.startActionMode(actionModeCallback)

Comment: To call inside your adapter you don't need to get the reference to your activity, you can create a function in your activity just to call the `startActionMode()` and pass the reference of your function to the adapter constructor, and then invoke this function inside your adapter through this reference. (if my answer helped you please check as right answer haha)